# Listening for Bluetooth Status

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm writing a code that listens for the Bluetooth device to become disconnected, then does something. How would I go about doing this? I'm not exactly sure what I want to put after it yet, figured I'd get this sorted out first. Hopefully I wasn't completely wrong with this code, as I'm new to developing. This is what I have so far:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

           if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action))
           { // This will be the followup action, once I figure out what I want it to be.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use the [BluetoothChat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) example to start with as coding with Bluetooth is pretty complex and it's nice to have working code.  What you want to look at is handleMessage() in BluetoothChat.java, and you'll need to save off the state.  When the state changes from BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED to BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE, the device has become disconnected.